# requirejs: load script/module from a web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, requirejs, breeze

I have a WebService that query a SQL database.  In a sql table, I store some javascript and I want to use it in a webpage using RequireJS.

I try this :

```
var url = "http://localhost:64952/breeze/app/Objectss?$filter=Id%20eq%201&$select=Script";
require([url], (test) => {
     debugger
     arguments[0];
});
```

The server respond correctly :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/05lE7.png

But I'm not sure RequireJS is able to load script like this.

I try something else :

```
var req = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Commands")
          .where("Id", "eq", "1")
          .select("Script");
dataservice.manager.executeQuery(req)
    .then((res : breeze.QueryResult) => {
        if (res.results[0]) {
            require([(<any>res.results[0]).Script], (hekki) => {
                debugger
            });
        }
    });
```

Doesn't work too...

Do you have any idea to help me please ?!

Comment: Your question is unclear. For your 1st example you say the server responds correctly but then say you are not sure RequireJS is "able to load scripts like this". Why not sure? You've got a `debugger` statement. Is it not hit? (Also, is "this" in "like this" referring to the previous or next example.) For the second example you say "doesn't work too". Saying it does *not* work *too* suggests that the first example is in fact not working. Moreover, if it does not work, then how is it not working? Error message? The `debugger` statement is not hit? Something you expect to happen does not happen?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! In the 2 examples, the debugger is hit... But i'm not able to call the script require has to load. I think require is not able to load script by calling a rest URL because when I put the URL in a software like "I'm On resting", the response is an object containing an Id, a type and a propertie Script.

Comment: With this in mind, I put a breakpoint in requirejs on the load fonction to try to understand what require do when loadind as url. The load function is the place where it add the script node to the document header. When I look this script node, in the first case, the textContent, text, innerHTML or outerHTML are empty and I can't see my script. In the second example when I look to this node, I  can see my script in the src attribute... I think for this case it's because require try tu use the var containing the script like an url or a source path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **[requirejs plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html)** responsible for loading dependencies via the breeze api you've put together...

**breezeloader.js:**

```
define({
    load: function (name, req, onload, config) {
        // load the script using the breeze api you've put together...
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Commands")
            .where("Id", "eq", name)
            .select("Script");
        dataservice.manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then((queryResult: breeze.QueryResult) => {
                var text = queryResult.results[0].Script;      

                // Have RequireJS execute the JavaScript within
                //the correct environment/context, and trigger the load
                //call for this resource.
                onload.fromText(text);
            });
    }
});
```

express dependencies that should be loaded with the breeze loader using the requirejs plugin syntax:

```
require(['breezeloader!1', 'jquery', 'foo'], function (hekki, jquery, foo) {

    ...

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!! I had some problems to make it works but this solution is just what I wanted !